# Error updating Android SDK to API Level 17

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, adt

I have updated the ADT version of to Ver 21. After I have updated the ADT and restarted the eclipse, I am getting the dialog below....

[image]

Once i open the SDK Manager, I can only see a part of the API level 17 updates, but not all..

[image]

And once i try to update the package, the prompt is not allowing me to update the package but it says API level 17 is missing.

[image]

I am running Eclipse 3.7. What can be done to update the API Level 17 properly?

Comment: have u tried Packages->Reload ?

Comment: This has done the trick for me... :-)

Comment: then u can probably accept it as answer to end this discussion. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Reload your sdk manager from `Packages->Reload`. May it work out.

Answer (score 4):

In Eclipse:

1. Go to `help` at the top of the screen.
2. Select `check for updates`

You first need to update your IDE and then update SDK.

This is because the Android SDK is updated separately from the Eclipse Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You could have to go and update the sdk first. You could goto - help - and check for updates and update the sdk. Once done, you could then re-launch the sdk manager and update the APK.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue...
Take a look at command line there was a folder
that can't be renamed at installation.
I fixed this by renaming the folder manually and reinstall the update.

I used this link for updating http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/